# How Gson knows which json element is to use which Deserializer

Tags: android, gson

I have the following json input. And know i am using Gson to parse.

```
{ 
  “type”: “type1”, 
  “date”: “Tue, 16 May 2017 07:09:33 +0000”, 
  “body”: 
  { 
     “formatA_1”: “aaa”, 
     “formatA_2”: “bbbcccddd” 
  } 
  "other": "info"
}

public class Data {

    private String type;

    private Long date;

    private Body body;

    private String other;
    ...
}
```

As i want to convert the date to long, So i implement the custom DateDeserializer.

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Long> {
    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return DateConvertUtils.convertStringDatetoLong(json.getAsString(), DateConvertUtils.SERVER_DATE_FORMAT);
    }
}

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Long.class, new DateDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

This is working. But i wonder, how the Gson knows that only the "date" element needs to use the DateDeserializer? How it knows that other elements no need to use DateDeserializer?

If I put more other custom deserializers, how it would know which element is to use which deserializer?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try changing private String other to private Long other

Comment: @Mars,  For all the type Long, it will use DateDeserializer() to parse it.  If this way, it can have some pitfall in using for complex and different data type.  In my code, without noticing, if Date parse exception, then return 0. So my other Long type becomes 0. The only way to solve it is if exception, return the original value? Is this the way to do that?

Comment: One moment, I'll answer below

Comment: Sorry, my first answer was way off. I tested it and got the below results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gson uses the last added deserializer for given type and uses the deserializer for all cases. In your case, it will use your deserializer for any and all Longs

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and explanation. So I should avoid the cases of 2 or more same type to parse with different deserializer class. I got it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes, maybe create a separate holder class for your Long like DateLong, with a Long property "value", then have your deserializer return a new DateLong with "value" set to what you parse